# Unexpectedly Found Nil SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I get the following error when there's contact between bullet and the plane.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

[image: Screenshot of error]

Plane Function:

```
func addPlane() {
    var myplane : SKSpriteNode?
    myplane = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "plane")
    let actualY = random(min: 100, max: size.height - myplane!.size.height/2)
    myplane!.position = CGPoint(x: size.width + myplane!.size.width/2, y: actualY)
    myplane!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: myplane!.size) // 1
    myplane!.physicsBody?.dynamic = false // 2
    myplane!.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategoryPowerUpOrbs
    myplane!.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
    myplane!.name = "plan"
    addChild(myplane!)//
    let actualDuration = random(min: CGFloat(2.0), max: CGFloat(4.0))
    let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: -myplane!.size.width/2, y: actualY), duration: NSTimeInterval(actualDuration))
    myplane!.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove]))

}
```

When the user touches the screen,  it will shoot a bullet with this funciton:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else {
            return
        }
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        var projectile : SKSpriteNode?
        projectile = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bomb")
        projectile!.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100.0)
        projectile!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: projectile!.size.width/2)
        projectile!.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        projectile!.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
        projectile!.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategoryPlayer
        projectile!.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = CollisionCategoryPowerUpOrbs
        projectile!.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
        projectile!.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 1.0
        projectile!.name = "shot"
        let offset = touchLocation - projectile!.position
        if (offset.x < 0) { return }
        addChild(projectile!)
        let direction = offset.normalized()
        let shootAmount = direction * 1000
        let realDest = shootAmount + projectile!.position
        let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(realDest, duration: 2.0)
        let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        projectile!.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]))
}
```

Function to hide the plane on contact:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let nodeB = contact.bodyA.node!
    if nodeB.name == "plan" {
        nodeB.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

I call the `addPlane` function in `ViewDidLoad` like this:

```
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
    SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.runBlock(addPlane),
        SKAction.waitForDuration(1.5)
    ])
))
```

Comment: You have a physics body with no node attached to it somewhere, that is why you are failing at the node! unwrapping

Comment: Why are you defining `myplane` and `projectile` as optionals? You give them values immediately afterwards, and then proceed to litter force unwraps through your code. Just define them as non-optional, and avoid force unwrapping like the plague.

Comment: use `if let` or `guard let` when doing `SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bomb")`, this way you can protect yourself and ensure that the sprite loads correctly. E.G.  `guard let projectile = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bomb") else{print("error")}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you code with a '?' to do a nil check:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

  let nodeB = contact.bodyA.node
  if nodeB?.name == "plan" {     
    nodeB?.removeFromParent()
  }
}
```

This solution will prevent the crash but has the disadvantage that some  unnecessary contact events are still triggered.

Removing a node inside didBeginContact should be avoided. This can lead to situations where the node is already removed (nil), but the PhysicsBody is still active. 
(see also the comments from KnightOfDragon)

Comment: A had sometimes the same issue, that a contact body has no node. It happens especially when multiple objects are on the screen and multiple collisions happened at once. And of course I checked, that I have not create physics bodies without a node. The nil checked solved my issue, because the next collision was detected immediately ofter the one with the nil. Not sure if this is a SpriteKit bug?

Comment: you are probably getting a nil because you kill the sprite without making sure that the physics body dies with it.  You do not remove in the update phase, you override the update end function and remove all nodes at that point

Comment: Maybe a timing issue? The node is removed in didBeginContact. Maybe the next collision happens while removing the node with the physicsBody is not completed?

Comment: yes you do not remove nodes in didBeginContact, Only remove them during the update end so you can check and know everything was verified to work properly

Comment: Yeah, certainly not a bug in SpriteKit, but rather what @Knight0fDragon said. I've answered this somewhere already, just can't find it. This can happen when you have 3 nodes contacting at the same time. SpriteKit can handle only contacts between two bodies at the time. So if you have A,B and C nodes, `didBeginContact` will be triggered 3 times, and contacts will be handled separately between A & B, A & C, and B&C. In first case (A&B), lets say that you are removing B from its parent ... So in third invocation of `didBeginContact` forced unwrapping will fail,because B.parent is nil.

Comment: So something like `didSimulatePhysics` or `didFinishUpdate` for removing nodes will probably work. And when I say forced unwrapping will fail because B.parent is nil, I meant to say, that B is removed from its parent. That would be more appropriate. And if nothing is retaining it (not defined as a property) it will be released. Still, its physicsBody stays alive a bit longer (obviously physics engine retains it until it finishes physics simulation). But because the B node is released, physicsBody's node property becomes nil. So the app crashes.